# Hide DIV when input field is blank

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I wonder if you could help me with an issue.

I am building a content template for an events page, that pulls data through using Advanced Custom Fields.

I have a field in the admin side which will be filled out when adding a new event. The field is called `show_info` with the ID `#acf-editor-46`.

On some events however this will be left blank, but the DIV that wraps around the content on the frontend will still show on the template, the DIV has the class `.show-info-wrapper`.

I would like it so when the `show_info` field is blank, the DIV `.show-info-wrapper` does not display on the front end.

I have made some progress from browsing around, you can see the code I have so far here:

HTML (Just a quick testing set up):

```
<textarea id="acf-editor-46" class="wp-editor-area" aria-hidden="true">1111</textarea>
<div class="show-info-wrapper">CONTENT</div>
```

**JavaScript + jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($('#acf-editor-46').val() == '' ){$('.show-info-wrapper').hide();}  

    $('#acf-editor-46').on('change' , function() {

         if( this.value != ''){

               $('.show-info-wrapper').show(); 
          }
          else{
               $('.show-info-wrapper').hide(); 
         }
    });
  });
```

It works on JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ha2nedfb/), however, it seems that on my WordPress site as the input and the DIV are not on the same DOM, it does not work.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: In your example, the `show-info-wrapper` does *not* wrap around the text area, is this example correct? "Not on the same DOM" -- what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the event of `#acf-editor-46` to `input`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($('#acf-editor-46').val() == '' ){$('.show-info-wrapper').hide();}  

    $('#acf-editor-46').on('input' , function() {  // Just change event to input

         if( this.value != ''){

               $('.show-info-wrapper').show(); 
          }
          else{
               $('.show-info-wrapper').hide(); 
         }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/jypwa6Lv/2/

Comment: This still does not seem to work for me. It seems that on my WordPress site as the input and the DIV are not on the same DOM, it does not work. "As the JS is calling to a box that is in the admin. It can't pull that value unless it and the .show-info-wrapper are on the same page (Without some overkill functionality)."

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$("#acf-editor-46").val()) {
// textarea is empty
}
```

try this to check textarea is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate event if textarea is rendered later.

```
$(document).on('change', '#acf-editor-46', callback);
```

Links:

1. https://api.jquery.com/on/
2. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<textarea>` and `<div>` are really siblings in this very order (your text contradicts the example) & if you're OK with adding a `placeholder` to the `textarea` & you only need [new-ish browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-placeholder-shown), there is a pure CSS solution:

```html
<textarea ... placeholder=" "> </textarea>
```

```css
.show-info-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.wp-editor-area:placeholder-shown + .show-info-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

[Here's a pen](https://codepen.io/bikubi/pen/BaKxjPv).